# Positioning multiple AJAX forms in a single DIV

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been searching for an answer for a couple days now and had no luck.

When using AJAX to bring in multiple forms into a DIV how can I position new forms not on top of the existing form?

I have a menu that calls in new forms into a working area. The new form being called in appears on top of the existing form(s). The forms are draggable but I would prefer to have the new form position itself off of the other one(s). Is there a way to do this?

I am using jQuery to handle AJAX and effects.

EDIT & ANSWER:

I just found out what was wrong. Sorry I didn't see this before. My forms were each in their own DIVs which were getting a 0 height. This is one of those facepalm moments. :P

Thanks for your responses guys. :)

BETTER EDIT:

I used the float:left advice and added in the 0 height again. Everything works great now.

Comment: By "on top of" do you mean they're being overwritten or they are superimposed on top of the original?

Comment: Some code showing how you're handling the positioning would be helpful.

Comment: They are superimposing. There ends up being a stack of forms in the top left corner of the DIV.

Comment: @Jack I am not handling positioning right now because I can't figure out how. I was hoping to get some direction here.

Comment: If you're using *position:absolute* on these forms, remove it.

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong. Reason is posted in the question. Thanks guys. It was a facepalm moment for me. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish - you could "float" your forms within your working area and just append new ones into the working area when you need to.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2dFr/1)**

Comment: Thanks for your example Rionmonster. :) Turns out it was my stupidity that was the problem. Reason in edit on initial post. And yes, your example helped. Makes it work even better. :) Thanks